# Magento2: How can add custom search boxes in admin grid for products?

Tags: magento2, magento-search

I want to add custom search box in product grid in admin. please find below screenshot: https://prnt.sc/o3tsso
How can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to add those. You already have searchboxes for (almost) every column in the grid.
Just click on the "filters" button on the top right part.
But if you insist in having search fields inside the column, below the header, I don't think it can be achieved easily. You will have to modify the way the ui-components work, or create your own ui-components.
Unfortunately I have no idea where to start on this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I want to do this according to requirement. I have tried to modify UI component but didn't get success still. Can you please help me for this. Thanks